# Admob, eCPM on waterfall mediation

Tags: admob

I do not really understand how mediation and display priority works on my rewarded ads

For example, I have a mediation group where there are biding and one waterfall

Usually my biding price is around $6 and the waterfall is very variable between $10 to $2

First I set optimized eCPM on my waterfall, it began great around $10 but then it went to $3 so I defined a manual eCPM to $10 thinking that ads with a lower $10 will not be displayed but ads are still displayed and the eCPM is around $3

- Is there any way to configure a minimum eCPM for waterfall ?
- Why my biding which are around $6 are not taken in priority and the $3 waterfall are shown instead of my biding ?

Comment: Supported partners' bidding & waterfall eCPMs are auto-optimised. You could try creating ad units with high eCPM floors & see if that works.

Comment: double check your ad sources. 
admob waterfall prices are just for display to order your ad units. 
For example if you use an applovin ad configured at 5$ ecpm and you set it inside admob in a 10$ waterfall it'll return 5$ ads (in average)